# How do I start a script for a button in HTML to change font size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, font-size

I'm not sure how to start a script that sets a font size when the button is clicked.
I'm supposed to have a button labeled normal, medium and large.

Answer (score 0):

There are **several** ways to change the properties of HTML entities:

1. Via the `onclick` attribute in HTML:

   `<button onclick="func()">Text</button>`

---

2. Via `id` or `class` attributes in the HTML code:

   `<button id="btnId">Text</button>`

   `<button class="btnClass">Text</button>`

   and the following JavaScript code -

   For id element:

   ```
   let btn_with_id = document.getElementById("btnId") // Getting element with specific id

   btn_with_id.onclick = () => {
       btn_with_id.style.fontSize = "55px" // Can be anything: em, % etc.
   }
   ```

   And for multiple class elements (if you want to change many items):

   ```
   let btns_with_className = document.getElementsByClassName("btnClass") // Getting elements with the same class
   for (let btn of btns_with_className) {
       btn.onclick = () => btn.style.fontSize = "55px"
   }
   ```

   Also we can add className with some pre-made properties
   `btn_with_id.classList.add("btnCustomClass")`

   In addition, there is another way of onclick event - `addEventListener()`

   Here's how it works:

   ```
   btn_with_id.addEventListener('click', event => {
       btn_with_id.classList.add("Your_class")
   })
   ```

If you want to change the button text based on the `font-size`, here is the solution:

```
if (btn_with_id.style.fontSize == "55px") btn_with_id.innerHTML = "Large" // Here can be different `fontSize` and `innerHTML` text
```

Answer (score -1):

Buttons that changes font size:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.body.style.fontSize = '12px';">Small</button>

<button type="button" onclick="document.body.style.fontSize = '16px';">Normal</button>

<button type="button" onclick="document.body.style.fontSize = '20px';">Large</button>
```

This sets the fontsize on the body element, so other elements that have their own font size set wont change, except if you used `em` or `rem` as your size unit.

Comment: Ah ok thanks that worked, out of curiosity what is em or rem? Im very new to HTML and CSS and Javascript

Comment: `em` and `rem` are units that change their size depending on font size. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units